# Can't manually scroll div on Android nor iPhone

Tags: iphone, android, html, webkit

I am making a web app for the Android and iPhone that has a div for content.  I can update the div programmatically and have it scroll down but I can't scroll using just my finger.

You can see it here: http://crosswordcoach.appspot.com/poc

Type in "Cookie firs" and then select that clue (obviously there are other bugs to work out!) and it will have enough hints to fill the screen.  With Chrome on a PC it works correctly and the list becomes scrollable if it is too big for the screen.  On the iPhone and Android it does not.

Does anyone know what the deal is?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhones cannot scroll absolute positioned `div`s by default, I believe.

[iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) might help.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great resource!